# How can I show a custom post type for users in the authors.php file?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, author, author-template

Here is the code I have.  It is showing 100 custom post known as campaigns.  I need it to only show the current users.  So author/joe should only show joe's campaigns.

```
  <?php

   if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :

    $curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);

    else :

    $curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));

     endif;

     ?>




<h2>Campaigns by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>



<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'post_type' => 'campaigns'

  );
query_posts($args);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">

        <?php the_title(); ?></a>,



    </li>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Don't use `query_posts`, ever. Don't even use a custom query. Use `pre_get_posts` to add your custom post type to the author pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `query_posts`, and for that matter any custom query to replace the main query. It is always problematic and it creates more problems that solving it.

Use the main query and make use of `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query as needed.

To solve your issue, remove the `query_posts` line, this is how author.php should look.

```
<?php

   if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :

        $curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);

    else :

        $curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));

    endif;

?>

<h2>Campaigns by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>

<?php

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">

        <?php the_title(); ?></a>,



    </li>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Add the following in your `functions.php` file

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_author() ) {

        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'campaigns' );

    }

});
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you.  There was a syntax error.  I had to add an opening php tag before the if statement in the loop to make it work.  Is that correct?

Comment: You are correct, sorry, missed that. Copy and paste error :-). Thanks for your feedback. I will correct that for future reference. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

**i dont see the problam in using WP_Query...**
it has an author parameter.

```
$cuser_id = get_current_user_id();

$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'campaigns',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  100,
    'author'            =>  $cuser_id,

);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        // BUILD AND DISPLY CAMPAIGN DATA
        $pid    =   get_the_ID();
        $ptitle =   get_the_title();
        $plink  =   get_permalink();

        echo '<li><a href="'.$plink.'">'.$ptitle.'</a></li>';

    }

} else {
    echo 'You have published any campaigns yet';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't use custom queries in place of the main query. The main query can be correctly modified with `pre_get_posts`

Comment: there is no need to use a filter. he can wrap this in a function and embed it inside the author.php page in any position he needs.

Comment: Hey I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE for the line of code $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

Comment: yee - forgot one ";" after the args array - revised answer if you hadent fixed this already then just copy - paste

Comment: I got another syntax error and had to add a ; after THEME_NAME) .  Now I just see title over and over again on author.php profiles.

Comment: Well, ofcourse... the THEME_NAME should be replaced with your own theme translation string. my apologies if you didnt grab that. or you can just replace the entire thing with you own string....  Returning the title is just a demo mode... to show you how it works - revised it again to return that same data as your loop.

Comment: The problem with using this on the author page rather than a pre_get_posts filter is that it's doing two queries - one which is the built in author query, and the second WP_Query here. That's why it's recommended to use pre_get_posts which modifies the main author page query, as it improves performance, i.e page load time.